# Creating a SQL statement to query a MySQL DB by comparing two field in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as example below:

Prices

ID**low**high**value

1**1**4**29.0

2**5**9**32.0

3**10**25**50.0

low and high are both INT

I've tried:
$SQL = "SELECT value from Prices WHERE low >= '2' AND high <= '2'
but I come up with zero (0) results returned where in this example I'm wanting to find 29.0

edited my table above as it was unclear after I saw it formated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see a high <= 2 in your example above.
You might wanna review that.

`$SQL = "SELECT value from Prices WHERE low >= '2' AND high <= '2'"`

The above code you showed us is correct.

I believe you want it switched around to find value 29.0:

`$SQL = "SELECT value from Prices WHERE low <= '2' AND high >= '2'"`

Answer (score 1):

@Rick beat me to the logical error in your query. Just gonna add you should use backtics around field and table names (at least for `value` here as I think that might be a future reserved keyword). Also, if `low` and `high` are `int` type, you shouldn't surround values for them in quotes. Though mysql might convert them accordingly, you are specifying strings.

```
SELECT `value` from `Prices` WHERE `low` <= 2 AND `high` >= 2
```